# Purpose of StatefulWidgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Here is an example of a StatefulWidget. But isn't it just boiler plate code? Why do we need two classes? Normally you copy&paste the `extends StatefulWidget` part but where is the purpose? Is there some hidden functionality? Or is it some kind of abstraction level? Why was this design chosen by the Flutter team?

```
 class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
      int someVar;
      Counter(this.someVar);

      @override
      _CounterState createState() => new _CounterState();
    }
```

And here is the State class. Wouldn't be this class sufficient? Why do we need two classes for a StatefulWidget?

```
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      ++_counter;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(children: <Widget>[
      new CounterIncrementor(onPressed: _increment),
      new CounterDisplay(count: _counter),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because all `Widgets`'s are immutable. This means that your `Counter` class in this case is immutable and thus also all variables should be `final`. The `State`, however, is not mutable.

You can check out [the documentation about the Widget class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html) to read more about its purpose.

> A widget is an immutable description of part of a user interface. [...] Widgets themselves have no mutable state (all their fields must be final). If you wish to associate mutable state with a widget, consider using a StatefulWidget, which creates a State object (via StatefulWidget.createState) whenever it is inflated into an element and incorporated into the tree.

Comment: That's not the reason actually. Currently answering

Answer (score -1):

Dividing a stateful widget in two is a requirement of some of flutter patterns. Widgets being the representation of a *pure function* you'd find in functional programming.

In fact React, a library from which flutter takes inspiration use two separate objects too. It's fairly obvious when using the following syntax :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State = {
       foo: 42,
    }
    ...
}
```

---

*Okey, but why is it that `State` and the `Stateful` subclass are deeply linked ? Why can't I use any class as `State` ?*

Ah, that's an interesting question ! For those who've used react before, this is something you can do out there. React can use any object as it's state. Flutter being so similar, why can't we too ?

After all, with a bit of tweaks there's nothing preventing the following syntax, not even the `@immutable` flag :

```
class MyStateful extends StatefulWidget<Video> {
  @override
  void dispose() {}

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(state.title);
  }
}
```

So why ?

A quote from flutter [documentation](https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/) :

> You might wonder why StatefulWidget and State are separate objects. In Flutter, these two types of objects have different life cycles. Widgets are temporary objects, used to construct a presentation of the application in its current state. State objects on the other hand are persistent between calls to build(), allowing them to remember information.

This would mean that we'd have all the lifecycle methods override you can have on `State` move to the `Stateful` subclass. Such as `initState`, but also `dispose` or `didUpdateWidget`. Which doesn't make sense considering widgets are just throwable objets that never update.

Comment: I do not like your example titled `MyStateful`. It really destroys the purpose of a `StatefulWidget` because your `MyStateful` will not be persistent and thus cannot update/hold any data. That is the reason we need `State`'s seperated, as I pointed out.

Comment: I don't like it too. But that's the syntax React picked. And that choice generate these kind of questions, so it's necessary to explain flutter could but didn't on purpose.

Comment: You said that my answer was wrong, but what have you actually added or explained other than comparing to React?

Comment: Your answer is wrong because the syntax I have provided is an alternative that is possible even with the reasons you listed.  I quoted directly from flutter documentation the real reason : Because they have different life-cycle. And I added that fusing them would imply `dispose`/`didUpdateWidget` would be on `Widget` which makes no sense

Comment: It is then not changing though. It is still `final`.

Comment: Nah because you can easily get around the `@immutable` flag. A  dart getter, or wrapping the state in a ValueListenable works just as well.

Comment: Also, why the downvote ? Downvoting without explaining why doesn't help